# How to read DECIMAL(38,10) using Morphlines conf file

Tags: solr, morphline

I want to read parquet files using Morphlines.
Reference:https://medium.com/@bkvarda/index-parquet-with-morphlines-and-solr-20671cd93a41

This Parquet file has DECIMAL datatypes. I do not find any documentation, how to deal with DECIMAL in Morphlines.
I am using below code in conf file which is not working.
============================test_morphlines.conf==============================
commands : [

```
 # Read the Parquet data  

{ readAvroParquetFile {
    projection:
      readerSchemaString:"""{ "type": "record"
         ,"name": "my_record"
         ,"fields": [

{"name": "audit_internal_id","type":["bytes","null"],"logicalType":"decimal","precision":38,"scale":10,"default":0 }
```

,{"name": "alert_id","type":["bytes","null"],"logicalType":"decimal","precision":38,"scale":10,"default":0 }
   ]
         }"""

```
    }
  }
```

Comment: Output logs:
DEBUG org.kitesdk.morphline.stdlib.LogDebugBuilder$LogDebug  - output record [{_attachment_body=[{"audit_internal_id": "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002#\u0014I��\u0000", "alert_id": "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u000F\u001A(��\u0000", "created_date": "2018-03-19", "event": "ALERT_REVIEWED", "comments": "Alert Reviewed, and Submitted by User:LV1234"}]

Comment: Here value of audit_internal_id and alert_id is not in human readable format.

Comment: Please help if any body has any suggessions